# In Go Ethereum private chain what is the maximum limit of number of transactions in a single block

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, private-blockchain, blocks

What is maximum limit of transaction packaging in single block ?
Can it be increased ? If yes how ?

Comment: it depends on multiple properties like the blocksize and blocktime

Comment: And the gas limit per block

Comment: any how can I increase up to 1000000 tx for each block ?